# How to show this function is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

let $f \geq 0$ be measurable on $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}$. If for any $\ n \geq 1$ there is a subset $E_n$ of $E$ with $\ m(E - E_n) < \frac{1}{n}$ and if

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow 0}\int_{E_n} \! f \ \text{exists}$ then show that f is lebesgue integrable.

What does it mean to say that the limit of the integral exists? I am assuming the

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow 0}\int_{E_n} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x =\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow 0}\int_{E_n} \! f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow 0}\int_{E_n} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

but is it **finite**?

First, I thought I am going to use the additivity property of the lebesgue integral over $E_n$ and its complement in $E$

But since we were given the limit over $E_n$, I thought about constructing a sequence of sets that converge to $E$.

Let $E_n = \{x \in E: f_n(x) \geq \frac{1}{n} \}$

then $E_n$ is monotone increasing to $E$. Then I can just apply the monotone convergence theorem of Levi and get that

$$\int_E \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow 0}\int_{E_n} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Since $RHS$ exists, so does $LHS$, and thus $f$ is lebesgue integrable.

Am I missing something? I don't see where we used the fact that  $\ m(E - E_n) < \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: You are not allowed to choose $E_n$'s.

Comment: I guess you mean "$f$ is Lebesgue integrable **on** $\boldsymbol{E}$"?

Comment: @Falcon this is the meaning by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument fails because a sequence $(E_n)$ is given to you and you cannot choose it.

It is understood that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{E_n} \! f \ \text{exists and is finite}$. Otherwise, the result is false.

First consider the case where $ \sum \mu (E\setminus E_n) <\infty$. Here $\mu (\lim \sup (E\setminus E_n)=0$ and so $\int_E f =\int _{E \cap D} f$ where $D$ is the complement of  $\lim \sup (E\setminus E_n)$ which is $\lim \inf (E\setminus E_n)^{c}$ . Apply Fatou's Lemma and use the fact that $\int_{E_n}  f$ is bounded to finish the proof.

For the general case you only have to replace $(E_n)$ by  a subsequence.

Comment: replace $(_)$ by a subsequence?

Comment: $\mu(E \setminus E_{2^{n}}) <\frac 1 {2^{n}}$. @C.Master

Comment: Are you saying that $\sum \frac 1n <\infty$? @C.Master

Comment: Is there a way to define the $\lim \sup (E\setminus E_n)$ in terms of a set (for infinitely many $n$)? @geetha290krm

Comment: It is the set of points of $E$ that belong to the complement of $E_n$ for infinitely many $n$ @C.Master

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learned so much from your proof over the last 2 days. I am done with the finite part. Can you direct me to how to construct a subsequence of the sequence of sets $(E_n)$. Like an example. I am not quite familiar with the concept. @geetha290krm

Comment: @C.Master The subsequence I am referring to is just $(E_{2^{n}})$.

Comment: Yea I got it now. Then use the same proof for the complement of $(E_{2^n})$. I was thinking about something else. Thanks. @geetha290krm